# Multer 'storage' option does not work while 'dest' one does

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, multer

I'm using Multer to upload and store files. If I use the `dest` option files upload to my `/uploads` folder with no problem. Whilst this works, it's saving the uploads like `2eb3f1a6def453f7a461c5de353b06f8` so I want to use the `storage` option, but for some reason this doesn't work or me and the files upload (logged in console), but wont save to the folder.

I've tried a few different ways of achieving this and none work. Can anyone point out what might be wrong?

```
{
    fieldname: 'attachments',
    originalname: 'myFile.pdf',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/pdf',
    destination: 'uploads/',
    filename: '2eb3f1a6def453f7a461c5de353b06f8',
    path: 'uploads/2eb3f1a6def453f7a461c5de353b06f8',
    size: 57638
  }
```

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require('path');
// const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" }); // this works, file saves to /uploads
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }); // this doesnt work/ files dont save to /uploads
// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded());
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    // cb(null, 'uploads/');
    // cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads');
    cb(null, './uploads');
   },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // cb(null , file.originalname);
    // cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());

    // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

// var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/', upload.array('attachments') , (req, res) =>{
  try {
    res.send(req.files);
    console.log('body', req.body);
    console.log('files', req.files);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send(400);
  }
});


module.exports = {
  path: '/api/upload',
  handler: app
};
```

Comment: What does it have to do with Nuxt? Do you have an error somewhere? Do you `async`/`await` your queries?

Comment: I'm building a Nuxt site, with NodeJS handling the file upload/save leveraging Nuxt's `Server Middleware`. Nuxt is submitting the data to my backend endpoint `/api/uploads` fine. Like I mentioned, Multer works with saving the files using the `dest` option, but `storage` (which I need to use wont work or some reason...

Comment: Also the console log that Ive added shows the success message. No errors. Just the files aren't saving to the older.

Comment: Why do you call `var upload = multer({ storage: storage })` before it's even declared?

Comment: Like I said, i've tried a few things. you cab see a commented out version above `app.post`. Copied wrong set of code into this SO message.

Comment: Yep, this is what I mean. Does it work when you uncomment it below? You're supposed to declare your things and then use them, not rely on hoisting.

Comment: It's worked... not sure why it didn't work before : / Thanks or the help!

Comment: Just got to sort out being able to access the actual files via the url now. When you go to `http://localhost:3000/uploads/attachments-1622452263114.pdf` it 404's

Comment: Do you see the file locally in your project? If you want to have access to it publicly, it may be a good idea to move the uploads to `/static`, this way Nuxt will allow you to access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `var upload = multer({ storage: storage })` after having it defined with  `multer.diskStorage` was enough to fix OP's issue.